# C# .NET - ItemCollection not compiling when passed as IList<type>

Tags: c#, .net, collections, types

I couldn't get code snippet #2 to work, so I had to change my logic to code snippet #1.  Can someone please explain why code snippet #2 wouldn't work?  I thought it would, since ItemCollection implements the IList interface...  I know the types that are stored in each listbox (listbox1 is string, and listbox2 is PictureInfo type).

(Note:  PictureInfo is my own defined type)

## 1:

```
    private void MoveImagesFromHCollectionToCollection(ItemCollection collectionMoveFrom, ItemCollection collectionMoveTo)
            {
                //Loop through All strings in the lstAll list box.  Then use each picture path to convert 
                //each picture into their own class
                foreach (string file in collectionMoveFrom)
                {
                    PictureInfo mp = ReturnPictureInfoTypeBasedOffFileExtension(img, file);
                    collectionMoveTo.Add(mp);
                    collectionMoveFrom.Remove(file);                         
                    //...
                }
            }

//Method call...
MoveImagesFromHCollectionToCollection(listbox1.Items, listbox2.Items);
```

## 2:

```
private void MoveImagesFromHCollectionToCollection(IList<string> collectionMoveFrom, IList<PictureInfo> collectionMoveTo)
        {
            //Loop through All strings in the lstAll list box.  Then use each picture path to convert 
            //each picture into their own class
            foreach (string file in collectionMoveFrom)
            {

                 PictureInfo mp = ReturnPictureInfoTypeBasedOffFileExtension(img, file);

                 collectionMoveTo.Add(mp);
                 collectionMoveFrom.Remove(file);
                 //...
            }
        }

//Method call...parameter 1 Listbox contains strings, parameter 2 Listbox contains objects of type PictureInfo
MoveImagesFromHCollectionToCollection(listbox1.Items, listbox2.Items);
```

Comment: When you say "I couldn't get X to work", please say *why* or *how* it doesn't work so we don't have to analyze your code line-by-line to figure out everything that might be wrong with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It inherits from the `IList` interface but not the `IList<T>` interface.  They are different because the latter accepts a specific type of object.

[IList Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.ilist.aspx)

[IList< T > Documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6.aspx)

Answer (score 3):

`ItemCollection` does not implement `IList<string>`.

`IList` (non-generic) is a different interface.